# How do I display the file size and format of attachments on a node templates?

Tags: 8, theming

In the node template I output the attached files (multiupload file field). Need to output the size and format of each file. I do it like this:

```
{% for file in node.field_news_files %}Size {{ file.entity.filesize.value }} in {{ file.entity.filemime.value }} format{% endfor %}
```

I get this result: Size 2227507 in APPLICATION/PDF format

The goal is to get this result: Size 2MB in PDF format

Can I output the data as I need in the node template or do I need to redefine it file-link.html.twig?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Format Bytes](https://www.drupal.org/project/format_bytes) module provides a Twig filter for that.

> In twig when you get the value of a file, the size is in simple bytes and if you're intending to show it to your end-user, it's not user-friendly, this simple Twig filter helps with that and renders the file size in it's respected: 'B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'
>
> Example usage:
>
> ```
> {{ node.field_attachment.entity.field_file.entity.filesize.value | format_bytes }}
> ```

The alternative would be to do the same formatting that module does in your own preprocess function for the template.

Answer (score 1):

My task is solved in two steps:

1. Install the "[Format Bytes](https://www.drupal.org/project/format_bytes)" module to output a clear file size
2. Output a field with files in the node.html.twig template, where we use the necessary markup and redefine the file format that we use in the field settings. In the example below, my final code is on twig without markup.

My field with files, which can have multiple values: "**field_page_files**"

```
{% if node.field_page_files is not empty %}
    {% for file in node.field_page_files %}
        
        {# Output the file label, if it is empty-output the machine name of the file #}
        {% if file.description is not empty %}
            {{ file.description }}
        {% else %}
            {{ file.entity.label }}
        {% endif %}
        
        {# Redefining the output of the file format, output of the file size by Format Bytes module #}
        ({% if file.entity.filemime.value == "text/plain" %}txt{% elseif file.entity.filemime.value == "application/pdf" %}pdf{% elseif file.entity.filemime.value == "application/rtf" %}rtf{% elseif file.entity.filemime.value == "application/rar" %}rar{% elseif file.entity.filemime.value == "application/zip" %}zip{% elseif file.entity.filemime.value == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" %}docx{% elseif file.entity.filemime.value == "application/msword" %}doc{% elseif file.entity.filemime.value == "image/jpeg" %}jpeg{% elseif file.entity.filemime.value == "image/png" %}jpeg{% elseif file.entity.filemime.value == "image/gif" %}gif{% elseif file.entity.filemime.value == "application/vnd.ms-excel" %}xls{% else %}file{% endif %}, {{ file.entity.filesize.value | format_bytes }})</span>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

In my example, I use the following file formats for the field: txt, pdf, rar, zip, doc, docx, jpg, jpeg, gif, png, xls, rtf

[image]